# How to control color and the intensity in a pcolor figure?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, simulation, colormap

I'm try in to simulate a Coronae (diffraction of droplet). There are color depends by wavelength, and intensity depends by diffraction. How can I control both color by wavelength (**lambda**) and intensity (**I**) ?
I can only control lambda to have different color of diffraction pattern now.

```
lambda=400;  % wavelength [nm] 
a=10e3;  % obstruct disc radius [nm](um)
x=linspace(-0.2,0.2,1000);
y=x;
[X,Y]=meshgrid(x,y);
r=sqrt(X.^2+Y.^2);
% diffraction pattern
u=2.*pi.*a./lambda;
J=besselj(1,u.*sin(r));
I=sqrt((u.*((1+cos(r))./2).*(J./sin(r))).^2);  % Intensity
% colormap
w=lambda;
if (w >= 380) && (w < 440)
    R = -(w - 440.) / (440. - 380.);
    G = 0.0;
    B = 1.0;
    elseif (w >= 440) && (w < 490)
        R = 0.0;
        G = (w - 440.) / (490. - 440.);
        B = 1.0;
    elseif (w >= 490) && (w < 510)
        R = 0.0;
        G = 1.0;
        B = -(w - 510.) / (510. - 490.);
    elseif (w >= 510) && (w < 580)
        R = (w - 510.) / (580. - 510.);
        G = 1.0;
        B = 0.0;
    elseif (w >= 580) && (w < 645)
        R = 1.0;
        G = -(w - 645.) / (645. - 580.);
        B = 0.0;
    elseif (w >= 645) && (w <= 780)
        R = 1.0;
        G = 0.0;
        B = 0.0;
    else
        R = 0.0;
        G = 0.0;
        B = 0.0;
end
c=[R,G,B]; 
h=linspace(0,1,256);  % illumination (intensity) from [0,1]
for i=1:length(h)
    S{i}=h(i).*c;
end
map=cell2mat(S');
% figure
pcolor(X,Y,I); shading flat; axis image; title([num2str(lambda)]);
colormap(map);
```

[This is what I'm trying to simulate. (picture from google search)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lQT5Y.png)

[And this is what I get so far (can change color by wavelength)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/odGy5.png)

Comment: well, the best way fo doing this is to instead of having a gigantic if-else, to write the formula that simulates your stuff.

Comment: @AnderBiguri The formula using in here is only for single wavelength of intensity, the if-else here is for the colormap I built due to the different wavelength.